# macOS applicationDockMenu remove universal items in the app's dockTile

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

I am developing a cocoa app for macOS and was manipulating the app's dock menu. I realize there are universal menu items such as "Options", "Show All Windows" and "Hide" in every app's dock menu.

In my case, those items/buttons do not work so I want to remove them. For example, "Options -> Keep In Dock" won't work because the executed application is a cloned one and will be deleted after quit(I know it is weird but that's what the app does).

Is there anyway that I can remove one or all of them? I think it might be impossible but a consultation won't do any harm.

[Universal items I'm trying to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTVw0.png)

Or, can I set the callback of "Show All Windows" or "Hide" programmatically? Update: I just found applicationWillHide/DidHide to set the callback of "Hide" item. But seems like I can not abort or abort its hide process unless I set the "canHide" window I don't want hide to false.

Comment: ""Options -> Keep In Dock" won't work because the executed application is a cloned one and will be deleted after quit" That sounds like something you should fix.

Comment: @Alexander Just like Parallel Desktop hybrid mode, agent apps will show in the dock. Our agent apps are dynamically generated, that is the difference. Currently this solution works for us.

Comment: @Alexander It's like we have a main app and other agent apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. They are inserted by the system and and you can not modify their behaviour.